# Unserstanding of "Maximum repetitive peak isolation voltage"

Tags: opto-isolator, isolation, rms

[Sometimes](http://www.vishay.com/docs/83526/83526.pdf) optocouplers has only **Isolation test voltage** parameter. [Sometimes](http://www.vishay.com/docs/83606/cny17.pdf) it has a bunch of parameters regarding isolation strength, including **Maximum repetitive peak isolation voltage**.

Strange thing is that this voltage is considerably lower than isolation **Isolation test voltage** or **Maximum withstanding isolation voltage**.

I'd say that **Maximum withstanding isolation voltage** measured in Volts **RMS** (which is important as sinusoidal amplitude Voltage equal to 1,41 * RMS Voltage) should result in **peak** Voltage equal to **RMS** * 1,41.

But it looks like the things are much more complicated than I expected.

Can anyone explain the fine points of the isolation strength terminology?

Why **Maximum repetitive peak isolation voltage** is about 10 times lower than **Isolation test voltage**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For sinusoidal stress voltages, VIORM and VIOWM are equivalent i.e. repetitive voltage and withstand voltage are the same.

However, when the working voltages are not sinusiodal (like in some inverters and motor drives) the lower "repetitive" value represents all types of waveforms that *could* be present.

Some text above stolen from [**this**](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwisiOCH9frNAhUlLsAKHUaADCsQFgglMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ti.com%2Flit%2Fslyy063&usg=AFQjCNE2jTRknsRaDxDwvPwwzJAUui2XFg&sig2=9aTyIIWfEbDO3kE848sjLA) useful document entitled: -

High-voltage reinforced isolation: Definitions and test methodologies

Written by Anant S Kamath and Kannan Soundarapandian from TI (see page 3).